PC not booting when hdmi cable is connected
I'm having problems with my pc which doesn't startup as normal if the HDMI is connected when I press the start button. The fan starts going at slightly higher speed than normal but nothing more happens. If i shut it down by pressing the power button it shuts down almost instantly. Therefore i guess that nothing actually starts.
If I remove the hdmi before pressing the start button and wait a few seconds before I plug it in then ubuntu starts up fine and everything works fine.
Edit: If there is a signal on the HDMI or DVI then it doesn't boot.
The pc is an older Acer aspire xc-605. The dvd-player is removed so is the old hdd. They are replaced by an ssd with latest and updated ubuntu. I have also removed the gpu-card. 2x 4GB RAM.
I have tried and failed:

Three different hdmi cables.
I have tried to get into bios without being connected to the
monitor. I pressed F2,F10 and DEL when doing that.
Also tried reboot from terminal to bios.
I have previously tried with hdmi connected to gpu-card
I have reseated the ram several times.
Changed ram to 2 other sticks.
I installed GPU-card again and tried with DVI to HDMI cable.

The pc does make a short beep at startup with or without the cable. It either means OK or dram refresh failure. I don't know if this is the normal behavior or not.
Any suggestions to what could be causing this or what to try next?
Edit 2: So i went back and connected the pc to my TV again and it worked perfectly! I also found out that my remapped keyboard didn't work as intended so when i thought I was hitting delete to enter BIOS it didn't work.
The monitor work perfectly with other pc:s.

It is very likely your computer has some hardware fault. Possibly a bad ground connection related to the HDMI port, or something else like that. If the issue is happening with your mainboard's "onboard" HDMI connection, the problem is likely with your mainboard, and you should replace that. However, you note that you have "previously tried with ... gpu-card" but you don't state what the outcome of that was. Did the computer boot OK, or did it have the same issue?

The same happens when connected to GPU card. It works if its not connected when booting.
The external graphics card is actually slower than the integrated for some reason so thats why I removed it.

Is the other end of the HDMI connected to a monitor? Does the problem still happen if there is nothing, or a different monitor/device connected to the other end of the cable? In a hardware issue like this you should be testing to isolate which piece(s) are the cause(s). Check every possible permutation until you know which device is the cause or contributing factor, then replace the bad pieces. Alternatively, take it to a competent local PC technician who will do the same.

If there is a signal on the HDMI or DVI then it doesn't boot. I just tried with power to monitor off and cable plugged in. If I wait a few seconds after boot to power on monitor then it works perfectly.

What do you mean by "signal"? Do you mean that when the cable is connected to a monitor the problem happens, and when the cable is NOT connector to a monitor at the other end, the problem doesn't happen? If so, have you tested this monitor with a different computer? Have you tested with a different monitor. I've already given the basic steps you need to follow. Please follow them and you'll have diagnosed your problem.

@music2myear if you write an answer I can accept it. The monitor does not workshop with my pc. We have narrowed it down to that.

Diagnosing hardware issues (nearly) always involves checking each component as separately as possible to isolate the components that are working and eventually finding the component(s) that are not working.
For this situation, the things that come to my mind to try are:

Try different cables (which it seems you've already tried).
Try cables with different things (and nothing) connected to the other end.

If different cables have the same symptoms, the problem is (probably) not the cables.
If you connect the other end of these cables to nothing or to a different  monitor and the symptoms persist, the problem is probably inside the computer, but if the symptoms go away when you connect the cables to a different monitor or to nothing, the problem may be with the monitor.
